# mapping two xmls with different rootelement name to the same java object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have

```
xml1:
<abc><name>hello</name></abc>

xml2
<xyz><name>hello</name></xyz>

I have one java class. 

@XmlRootElement(name="abc") (this 
public class Foo{
   @XmlElement
   String name;
}
```

I do not want another class, but would like to accomodate xml2 with the Foo class itself.
I'm okay to intercept or modify it during pre-marshalling/pre-unmarshalling.

Thanks!

}

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you mean by "I don't want another class", maybe this will work out for you:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class JaxbBindTwoRootElementsToSameClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml1 = "<abc><name>hello</name></abc>";
        String xml2 = "<xyz><name>hello</name></xyz>";
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).createUnmarshaller();
        Object o1 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml1));
        Object o2 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml2));
        System.out.println(o1);
        System.out.println(o2);
    }

    @XmlSeeAlso({Foo.Foo_1.class, Foo.Foo_2.class})
    static class Foo {
        @XmlRootElement(name = "abc")
        static class Foo_1 extends Foo {}

        @XmlRootElement(name = "xyz")
        static class Foo_2 extends Foo {}

        @XmlElement
        String name;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo{name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Foo{name='hello'}
Foo{name='hello'}
```

It has the benefit of using JAXB almost exactly the way you usually would. It's just a slightly unconventional class organization. You even only have to pass `Foo.class` to the JAXBContext when you create it. No tinkering with JAXB internals needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Unmarshalling**

You could use the unmarshal methods that take a class parameter.  When a class is specified the JAXB implementation does not need to use the root element to determine the class to unmarshal to.

**Marshalling**

When marshaling you can wrap the root object in a JAXBElement to provide the root element information.